# Is it any possibility to change the image border automatically according to image shape?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

When the user changes the square image to a circle image the border remains square. Is it any way to change the border to circle automatically?

Comment: Remember that this is not a general help forum: you need to put in the work to [ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) if you want good answers. As is, you've not provided any details, so no one will be able to answer this.

Comment: yes we can make border according to image shape but you need to share your code example then we could help.

Comment: thank you so much. i solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, please try this approach:

HTML:

```
<div class="image-cropper">
      <img src="your-image" alt="avatar" class="profile-pic">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-cropper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.profile-pic {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: -25%; //centers the image
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

It will circle your image perfectly as we have profile pic in social media.